# Getting 'with_frame(":1")' in my tests

Tags: java, ruby, swing, marathontesting

My app has the ability to 'load' a deal. After it's loaded, a new frame renders with the deal's information.

I'm having trouble targeting this frame with Marathon. I am able to target other parts of the app, but if I control-click on the new frame, I get `with_frame(":1")` in my scripts. When I try to replay, Marathon cannot identify the frame, and hangs.

I surmise it has something to do with a `name` or `id` attribute on the panel, though I don't know much about Java. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: When I use `dump_components()` I see the component: `<:1> - com.intex.jtrader.UI.DealInstance`. How can I target this?

Comment: Does the internal frame have a title? Are there more than one internal frames being displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@DanielDiazCarrete was correct, I added

```
this.setTitle("SomeTitle");
```

to my frame, and Marathon was able to identify it.